# Powershell methods to 1) determine if XML values exist, and 2) replace values

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
  <Test1Properties>
    <Property1>replace this</Property1>
  </Test1Properties>
  <Test1Sources>
    <Source1>
      <SourceReference>sourceref</SourceReference>
      <SourceType>None</SourceType>
    </Source1>
    <Source2>
      <Source2Properties>
        <Provider>prov</Provider>
        <ProviderKey>some-guid</ProviderKey>
      </Source2Properties>
    </Source2>
  </Test1Sources>
</Test1>
```

Given the xml above, there are 3 tasks that I need to accomplish in Powershell:

1. Replace the value of <Test1><TestProperties><Property1> with *new-value*
2. Verify that <Test1><TestSources><Source1><SourceType> value = None
3. How to determine if <Test1><Test1Sources><Source2><Source2Properties> exists within <Source2>

I'm assuming reading into an xml variable is the best way to start?  Like:

```
[xml]$xmlAttr = Get-Content -Path TestFile.xml
```

I hardly use Powershell at all much less with XML, so hoping these are fairly straightforward asks.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are some examples of how to handle your XML data:

```powershell
# Deserialize the XML text Option 1.
# This is syntactically simpler but is susceptible to encoding issues.
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path TestFile.xml

# Deserialize the XML text Option 2. Must use full path in Load method.
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load('C:\Temp\TestFile.xml')

# Update Node Property1 value
$xml.Test1.Test1Properties.Property1 = 'new value'

# Return True if SourceType node has value of None
$xml.Test1.Test1Sources.Source1.SourceType -ceq 'None'

# Return True if Source2Properties Exists as a child node of Source2
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Test1/Test1Sources/Source2/Source2Properties") -is [System.Xml.XmlElement]

# Save results in your xml file. Must use a full path in Save() method.
$xml.Save('C:\temp\TestFile.xml')
```

Comment: Everything needed in a concise, efficient, well-documented answer.  Thanks so much!